# How to pass JTable data to JTextArea using multiple JFrames?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtable

I am trying to create a simple library management system. I tried to pass the `JTable` data to another `JTextArea` in another `JFrame`. I try it in various ways, but I can't get success.

Here is the code of the table from the first frame.

```
public static Object showdata() {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    int Row = table.getRowCount(), Col = table.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] table = new Object [Row][Col];
    for(int i=0; i<Row; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<Col; j++) {
            table[i][j] = model.getValueAt(i,j);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Here is the code of the text area in another frame where I want to show the table's data from previous frame.

```
public static void check() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    EntryBooks eb = new EntryBooks();
    countarea.append((String) EntryBooks.showdata());
}
```

And It gives me an error like:

```
javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: You could use `toString` on the value returned by EntryBooks.showData instead of casting to String.

Comment: I use toString but it gives me nothing.I think I have another problem to return type in tablemodel. can you help me which object or Strings I should return from showdata()?

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.